# Is there a way of stoping Timer inside an update panel via jquery?

Tags: jquery, .net, webforms

I'm using .net webforms and want to stop or initiate a Timer element directly from jquery. Anyone know a way of doing that?

Here is my timer:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer" runat="server" OnTick="UpdateServers" Interval="60000">
        </asp:Timer>
        <div id="content">
            <asp:Repeater ID="serverList" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <label class="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "HealthState") %>">
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DisplayName") %></label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: It uses setTimeout internally, take a look at the generated script, find the name it gives the timeout, and stop it like this: http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/javascript/clear-timeout.php

Comment: Actually it isn't... I took a look at Sys.UI.Timer and it has an enabled attribute, but I just can't change it to false.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't user window.setTimeout? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx `The accuracy of when the Timer control posts back to the Web server depends on the accuracy of the ECMAScript (JavaScript) window.setTimeout function that is running in the browser.`

Comment: From the javascript that web developer plugin gave to me I didn't found setTimeout.

Comment: Well given the timout is difficult to get to, have you considered a hidden value that the server code can read that you can use to redirect the code path on the server to turn the timer off instead of executing the normal postback server code?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you mean. But I manage to solve my problem with js, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried and found a solution:

```
timer = $find('ContentPlaceHolder1_Timer'); 

timer.set_enabled(false);
```

It stopped the timer.